# Laravel: Undefined variable: data

Tags: php, laravel

My controller page code like this:

```
    public function getCategoryName()
{
    $category = Http::get('https://gorest.co.in/public-api/categories');
    if (count($category['data']) > 9)
    {
        $data = array_slice($category['data'],0,10);
        return view('layouts.header', ['data'=> $data]);
    }
}
```

In my layouts.header blade code not working $data variable:

```
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="main_nav">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
            @foreach($data as $item)
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">
                        {{$item['name']}}
                    </a>
                </li>
            @endforeach

        </ul>
    </div>
```

And returning this error code: Undefined variable: data (View: /home/vagrant/www/restapi/resources/views/layouts/header.blade.php)

Comment: Post your route

Answer (score 0):

Does $category['data'] returns type as an array when you dump before array_slice ?

simply try :

```
var_dump($category['data']);
die();
```

or

```
dd($category['data']);
```

Comment: Yes, i got the data so its true but not sending in blade